# Why doesn't the member func of nested class need a complete type?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

Example:

```
 class A
{
  class B
  {
    A c;//error!A is an incomplete type
    void test() { A b;/*OK,but why?*/ }
  };
};
```

The code snippet seems strange for me,what's the difference between the two usage of `A`?

Comment: a member would be recursive, a method that calls a superclass isn't at all... I dont understand why this would be counter-intuitive

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[class.mem]/6 specifies that:

> A class is considered a completely-defined object type (6.9) (or complete type) at the closing `}` of the
>   *class-specifier*. Within the class *member-specification*, the class is regarded as complete within function
>   bodies, default arguments, *noexcept-specifiers*, and default member initializers (including such things in
>   nested classes). Otherwise it is regarded as incomplete within its own class *member-specification*.

The definition of an object (as in `A b;` or `A c;`) requires the object to have a complete type. As the paragraph above states, the class type is incomplete within its own definition, except in certain places: namely, inside member function bodies and a few other places.

This rule makes it possible to write nontrivial code inside member functions defined inline while also prohibiting a class from containing itself (directly or indirectly).

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the compile error:

```
prog.cpp:8:7: error: field ‘c’ has incomplete type ‘A’
     A c;//error!A is an incomplete type
       ^
prog.cpp:4:8: note: forward declaration of ‘class A’
  class A
        ^
```

`Class A` is a [forward-declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Forward_declaration) which:

> Declares a class type which will be defined later in this scope. Until the definition appears, this class name has incomplete type. This allows classes that refer to each other:

For `class A` is not "fully" defined until `class B` is.

Thus, `class A` is a forward-declaration and an incomplete type.

However, for

```
void test() { A b;/*OK,but why?*/ }
```

> If forward declaration appears in local scope, it hides previously declared class, variable, function, and all other declarations of the same name that may appear in enclosing scopes:

Thus, it is fine to have `A` declared in local scope.